# Scaling POSIXlt data in histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

How to change the labels at x-axis in the form "2013-07-01 00:30:00"?

```
library(ggplot2)

a<-as.POSIXlt("2013-07-01 00:30:00")
b<-as.POSIXlt("2013-07-5 00:30:00")
aI<-as.numeric(a)
bI<-as.numeric(b)

times<-sample(seq(aI,bI,by=2),100)
ggplot(, aes(x=times)) + 
geom_histogram(aes(y=..count..),binwidth=10000, colour="black") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45))
```

And I looking for a function to add a curve like

```
 geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666")
```

but at the plot above, so that the curve fits on the ..count.. property.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing numeric x values to `ggplot`. You should pass datetime values and use `scale_x_datetime`:

```
times <- sample(seq(a, b, by = 2), 100)

library(scales)
ggplot(, aes(x = times)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y= ..count.. ), binwidth = 10000, colour = "black") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

You cannot add the density to the plot because the y-axis scales don't fit (neither with the density nor with the counts from `stat_density`). If you only care about the shape of the density curve you could use `geom_density(alpha = .2, fill = "#FF6666", aes(y = ..scaled.. * 7.5))`.

**Edit:**

According to your comment you seem to want this:

```
ggplot(, aes(x = times)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y= ..density..), binwidth = 10000, colour = "black") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) +
  geom_density(alpha = .2, fill = "#FF6666")
```

Which is confusing because you specified `y = ..count..` explicitly in `geom_histogram` (although it is the default).

Comment: Many thx, if I want more labels I schould also use `scale_x_datetime`. Respective to the density function, I ment Iam looking for a curve which fits this histogram like the geom_density fits geom_histogram(..density..).

Comment: I edited, but suspect I don't get you. Since a density function is continuous and a histogram is discrete, you cannot have count values of the same magnitude. So I am unclear what you would like to get, other than the scaled density values as shown in my answer.

Comment: I tried that also before, but I had no idea how to combine it with ``ggplot(, aes(x = times)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill= ..density..), binwidth = 20000, colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "green", high = "red") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) +
  geom_density(alpha = .2, fill = "#FF6666")`

Comment: FYI you're almost always better off using `POSIXct` rather than `POSIXlt`